# App crashes when trying to record audio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio-recording

So I'm trying to make a simple app, that records audio as long as the imagebutton is touched and held. This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //PREPARE MEDIA RECORDER
    final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.reset();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile("/easyvoicenotepad/test.mp3");

    //PREPARE
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //IMAGE BUTTON
    final ImageButton recBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.recButton);
    recBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                recBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
                recorder.start();
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                recBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_btn);
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Edited Logcat file:

```
07-30 13:53:09.423: E/MediaRecorder(10586): start called in an invalid state: 4
07-30 13:53:09.423: E/InputEventReceiver(10586): Exception dispatching input event.
07-30 13:53:09.423: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:48)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7379)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at     android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-30 13:53:09.431: E/MessageQueue-JNI(10586):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:48)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7379)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1910)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-30 13:53:09.438: E/AndroidRuntime(10586):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem is that the app crashes as soon as I compile it, after I added the audio recorder feature.

I have permissions set, now my app crashes as soon as I touch the ImageButton

Comment: Do you have `< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" / >` in the `Manifest`?

Comment: What about `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` ?

Comment: I've actually found an official bug logged here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5063

Comment: let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Sadly no, still getting an error, I updated the logcat and the code tho

Comment: You should also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />` in the `Manifest`.

Comment: Also in the MONTION_EVENT.ACTION_UP add: `recorder.stop();
    recorder.reset();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;`

Comment: Did all that, but still crashes :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `permission` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem, I forgot to set permissions. But my app still crashes. Execpt now it crashes as soon as I touch the imagebutton. Any idea what could still be the problem?

Comment: @Matthew logcat for that ? ie. exception name ?

Comment: @Matthew you have problem with starting recoding now visit http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/06/voice-recording-in-android.html tutorial

Comment: @Matthew you can also try http://www.devlper.com/2010/12/android-audio-recording-part-1/  and  http://www.devlper.com/2010/12/android-audio-recording-part-2/

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer :) I'm sure I'll make it work with the tutorials that you linked me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments below the question, change the whole code, so that the `onTouch` is isolated from `onCreate()`. It should look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{

  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
      recBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
      recorder.start();
      return true;
  }
  else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      recBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_btn);
      recorder.stop();
      recorder.reset();
      recorder.release();
      recorder = null;
  }

return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how the whole code would look like outside the oncreate? I'm still getting used to all this so I have some problems doing this :/

Comment: Even though an answer is already accepted - it's easy, just make recorder and recBtn publicly visible, so that the `onTouchEvent()` can see and manipulate them. You can put the declaration of `final ImageButton recBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.recButton);` in the `onTouchEvent()`, the recorder must be made public, remove all the code below the comment "//IMAGE BUTTON".

Answer (score 0):

add permission into AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have declared recorder object as final at - final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

final means constant and a constant member can not be updated using the code. 
So try making it static or private, i mean other than final.

private MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

Comment: I can't make it any other than static because it's inside the oncreate

Comment: Hi, your code looks fine, Have you declare external storage write permission in android manifest file -                             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: If it still crashing , then i can think of only one thing, the path to external storage.</br> try - `mFileName =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();<br/>
        mFileName += "/easyvoicenotepad/test.mp3";` <br/>and then pass mFileName to setOutputFile as<br/> recorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);`